# Implementing the SVHN CNN architecture in Srivastava et al. 2014 Dropout paper

Tags: keras, tensorflow, convolution, deep-learning

I am trying the implement the CNN architecture introduced in Srivastava et al. 2014 Dropout paper (appendix B.2), for the SVHN dataset. I implemented only the convolutional layers part, without dropout or any regularization for the moment, following this description of the mentioned paper:
"The convolutional layers have 96, 128 and 256 filters respectively.
Each convolutional layer has a 5 × 5 receptive field applied with a stride of 1 pixel. Each
max pooling layer pools 3 × 3 regions at strides of 2 pixels."

This is my code, implemented in TensorFlow 2.0 with Keras API

```py
    from tensorflow.keras import layers, Sequential

    model = Sequential(name= "fMap_svhn_DANN")

    model.add(layers.Conv2D(filters= 96, kernel_size= 5, activation= 'relu', input_shape= (32,32,3)))
    model.add(layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size= 3, strides= 2))

    model.add(layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size= 5, activation= 'relu'))
    model.add(layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size= 3, strides= 2))

    model.add(layers.Conv2D(filters= 256, kernel_size= 5, activation= 'relu'))
    model.add(layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size= 3, strides= 2))

    model.add(layers.Flatten())
```

And this is the error I get"

```
Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 5 from 4 for 'conv2d_11/Conv2D' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [?,4,4,128], [5,5,128,256].
```

Any idea to help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that your input shape was too small by the time it reached the last Conv2D layer.

By removing the last `Conv2D` and `MaxPool2D` layer, this is how the model looks like:
[image]

You can see that the last output before the `Flatten` layer has height and width of 4, which is smaller than your `kernel_size` of 5 in the last `Conv2D` layer.

Heres what you can do:

1. Increase the input image height and width OR
2. Set `padding='same'` in the `Conv2D` layers

Comment: I cannot change the input dimensions as they were used in the mentioned paper, so I will go for option 2.